# Rails - Use parent record column value in calculation on child scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these models

```
ModelOne
    has_many :model_twos

    integer :length_in_hours

ModelTwo
    belongs_to :model_one
```

I need to make either a scope or class level method on model_two that uses the model_one hours field in a calculation, something like this:

`scope :in_range, -> {includes(:model_one).where('created_at <= ?', DateTime.now + (model_one: {:length_in_hours}).hours)}`

but I can't quite get it to work and none of the searches I've done for it give a relevant answer

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Probably you can't do this in pure ruby/rails... you may need to re-write in SQL have you tried searching on that, but using the SQL-relevant keywords?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with `scope :in_range, -> {joins(:model_one).where("(model_twos.created_at + ((model_ones.length_in_hours * 3600) || ' second')::interval) > ?", DateTime.now)}`

Comment: Great work - add it as an answer so that if other people have the same question they can see that the issue has a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing the where in sql and casting the parent column into a seconds interval

`scope :in_range, -> {joins(:model_one).where("(model_twos.created_at + ((model_ones.length_in_hours * 3600) || ' second')::interval) > ?", DateTime.now)}`